# How to get a List<XElement> from this XML?

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I have a block of XML similar to the following:

```
<factsheet>
<bilcontents >
  <config name="1" />
</bilcontents>

<singlefactsheet includeInBook="true">
  <config name="7" />
  <fund id="630" />
</singlefactsheet>

<doubleFactsheet includeInBook="true">
  <config name="8" />
  <fund id="623" />
  <fund id="624" />
</doubleFactsheet>

<tripplefactsheet includeInBook="true">
  <config name="6" />
  <fund id="36" />
  <fund id="37" />
  <fund id="38" />
</tripplefactsheet>
</factsheet>
```

Is it possible for me to get a list of XElements that contains each of these, as long as `includeInBook="true"`, and with each element I can then deal with it based on the type of node.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Absolutely:

```
 var list = doc.Root
               .Elements()
               .Where(x => (bool?) x.Attribute("includeInBook") == true)
               .ToList();
```

Dealing with nullable Booleans can be a little odd, btw. An alternative approach for the lambda expression could be:

```
x => (bool?) x.Attribute("includeInBook") ?? false
```

or

```
x => (string) x.Attribute("includeInBook") == "true"
```

Comment: Thanks Jon, I actually worked out something similar on my own so I posted it below.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I worked out, though Jon pretty much beat me to the punch

```
var inBook = nodes.Descendants()
    .Where(xx => xx.Attribute("includeInBook") != null)
    .Select(xx => xx).ToList();
```

Comment: That's only verifying whether the attribute *exists* - if would include `includeInBook="false"` elements which is surely not what you want. Note also that the `Select` call is redundant.

Answer (score 0):

Alternately, you could use the built-in XPath extension methods methods (they live in `System.Xml.Xpath`:

```
XDocument doc;
// ...
var includeInBook = doc.XPathSelectElements("/factsheet/*[@includeInBook = 'true']")
```

Read as:

- `/factsheet`: select the element 'factsheet'
- `/*`: then choose all children
- `[ ... ]`: read square brackets as "where"

  - `@includeInBook = 'true'`: the attribute "includeInBook" has content equal to 'true'

Answer (score 0):

You should consider creating data structures for this XML and using "serialization". This would be a much cleaner way to interact with this data model. Just something to consider...